# Null pointer dereferencing

Tags: c++

```
void func() 
  {
    char *p = "Test String 2";
    if (p != NULL) { }
    p[0] = 0;
 }
```

Does the p[0]=0 Statement nullify the character? Are we dereferencing a null pointer on the p[0]=0 line?

Comment: `p[0]=0` is not dereferencing a NULL pointer, but it attempts to modify a read-only string literal, which is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: It's not `NULL` since you've set `char *p` to some literal. And your test on `NULL` doesn't do anything, it just executes "nothing" if `p` is not NULL

Comment: The subscript `p[0]` is identical to `*(p + 0)`. Hence, the result is a reference to the pointee. The assignment `p[0] = 0;` would assign the `(int)0` to the pointee (implicit conversion to `char` included). Please, consider that `"Test String 2"` is a `const char [14]`. Writing to it is not allowed.

Comment: I don't understand what you think "nullify the character" means.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> char *p = "Test String 2";
> ```

This is ill-formed in C++. String literals are arrays of const chars which do not implicitly convert to a pointer to non-const char (since C++11; such conversion was allowed but deprecated in older standard versions).

Avoid using pointers to non-const for pointing to string literals.

> Does the p[0]=0 Statement nullify the character?

It would assign the character with the null terminator character. For clarity, I would recommend using a character literal instead of integer literal:

```
p[0] = '\0';
```

However, since you modify a string literal, the behaviour of the program is undefined. Don't modify string literals.

> Are we dereferencing a null pointer on the p[0]=0 line?

No. A pointer initialised with a string literal is not null pointer.

---

P.S. Don't use `NULL` macro in C++. Use `nullptr` instead which has replaced all use cases that `NULL` may used to have had.

Comment: This answers the question(s) as asked, but I think elaborating the implications of the first paragraph as consequences for the second paragraph would be helpful. If it cannot be converted to pointer to  non-const char then assigning the terminator is not clean.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a C-style string like `char *p = "Test String 2";` does a couple of things

- Allocates some memory space statically to hold the sequence of characters `T,e,s,t, ,S,t,r,i,n,g, ,2, \0` - this may happen well before this function actually runs.
- Sets the value of `p` to the *address* of the start of that sequence.

That is, `p` will be some memory location, and `p[0]` will be the character `T`.

This has some implications for your code:

- `p` will not ever be `NULL`. If it is, something terrible has happened. For almost any compiler you care about, the sequence of characters will have been loaded as part of the executable when it was launched.
- `p[0]` does *not* dereference a NULL pointer, for the same reason.
- `p` points to a chunk of memory that you really shouldn't be modifying - it will possibly work, but that's not the same as "it's guaranteed to work". It can break in surprising ways.

Comment: For that last bullet point, in fact, `p` points to a chunk of memory that **you are not allowed** to modify. +1.